# Interpreting Big O Loops and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, time, big-o

So, I know I'm going wrong in my thinking but my answer for all three pieces of code is that they are O(n^2).

Can someone tell me if I'm wrong?

If yes, can you help me think through how to solve similar problems. Thank you in advance!

```
    public static int firstLoop(int[] arr) { 

       int sum = 0; int n = arr.length; 
       int limit = n * n; 
       for ( int j = 0; j < limit; j += 2 ) { 
          sum = (sum + arr[j / n] ) % 100; 
      } 
   return sum; }


     public static int withLoop(int[] arr) { 

    int sum = 0; int n = arr.length; 
    int j = 1; 
    int limit = n * n; 
    for ( j= limit - 1; j > 0; j /= 2 ) { 
    sum = (sum + arr[j / n] ) % 100; } 
    return sum; }

   public static int fwLoop(int[] arr)

    {  int sum = 0; 
      int n = arr.length; 
      int limit = n * n; 
      for ( int k = 0; k < limit; k += 2 ) { 
       int t = 1; for ( j = limit - 1; j > 0; j /= 2 ) { 
       t = (t + arr[j / n] ) % 100; 
      } sum = (sum + t + arr[k / n] ) % 200; 
    } return sum; 
 }
```

Comment: Please edit the question and format your code.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! I don't know what changes to make to the question  to make it more pertinent..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first piece of code runs in `O(n^2)` as you rightly said because `limit` is of size `n^2`
2. The second however does `j/=2` which divides the length of `limit` each time by `2`, therefore the loop will run for k times where `k=log(n^2) = 2log(n)` therefore it is of `O(log(n))` order
3. The third is a combination of first and the second, it runs in `O((n^2)*log(n))` time

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Super helpful!! I need some practice with the second one, determining when it is log n. Are there any similar pieces of code I can practice on?

Comment: @chocolateAndMath Think about it this way, you are dividing `n^2` by `2`, `k` times, until it becomes `1` i.e `(n^2)/(2^(k))=1` simplify this, it gives `k=2*log(n)`, there are plenty of sorting and searching algorithms that have `log(n)` in them

Comment: I understand much better now. Thank you Oswald!